# Get data between two pipes present in payload

Tags: regex, ruby, regex-group

I have recently started learning regex in ruby and I wanted to extract specific data fro payload.
My payload looks something like this:

> 2021-02-01T16:06:06.703Z CEF:0|ABCD|Sample text|Numbers|Sample random Text |**This value is random and i want to take this value out from payload**|9|rest of the payload

Since my data is present between pipes (||), I wrote this regex:

```
(?<=\|)[^|]++(?=\|)
```

But the problem is, this regex is taking all the values present between `|` `|`.

Can anyone help me extract value between **5th** pipe `|` and **6th** pipe `|`.

Comment: Why not `s.split('|')[5]`?

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply. But i need it with regex..

Answer (score 2):

You wish to extract the text that is between the 5th and 6th pipe. You can do that with the following regular expression.

```
r = /\A(?:[^|]*\|){5}\K[^|]*(?=\|)/
```

```
str = "2021-02-01T16:06:06.703Z CEF:0|ABCD|Sample text|Numbers|Sample random Text |My dog has fleas|9|rest of the payload"
```

```
str[r] #=> "My dog has fleas"
```

```
"a|b|c|d|e|My dog has fleas"[r]
  #=> nil
```

We can write the regular expression in *free-spacing mode* to make it self-documenting. Free-spacing mode causes Ruby's regex engine to remove all comments and spaces before parsing the expression (which means that any spaces that are intended need to be protected, by escaping them, by putting them in a character class, etc.).

```
/
\A       # match beginning of the sting
(?:      # begin a non-capture group
  [^|]*  # match any character other than a pipe zero or more times
  \|     # match a pipe
){5}     # end non-capture group and execute it 5 times
\K       # discard all previous matches and reset the start of the
         # match to the current location
[^|]*    # match any character other than a pipe zero or more times
(?=      # begin a positive lookahead to assert that the next
         # character is a pipe
  \|     # match a pipe
)
/x       # invoke free-spacing mode
```

---

Another way is to remove `\K` and add a capture group:

```
str[/\A(?:[^|]*\|){5}([^|]*)(?=\|)/, 1]
  #=> "My dog has fleas"
```

---

Of course, you don't need to use a regular expression for this:

```
str.count('|') > 5 && str.split('|')[5]
  #=> "My dog has fleas"
```